# Issue with running application on iOS9 XCode 7

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios9

After several hours of investigation I am stuck with this one. After migrating from Swift to Swift2 I manage to deal with all the errors, but in the end I got clang error:

> ld: file not found:
>   -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I am not really sure why does this happen nor how I can resolve it. Some of you got similar problem ?

I tried :

- close/open XCode
- clean build
- clean build folder
- delete derived data
- tried to add another device (Devices screen, add simulator)
- tried to build for iOS device ( same error, just instead of iphonesimulator i got iphoneos )
- opened particular folder, everything is there
- I am able to open iOS simulator from code

**EDIT, Oct-9-2015:**

After a bit more investigation, I found out following:

- Pods compile correctly. Every one of them.
- If I remove iphonesimulator/iphoneos they don't work
- Tried to clear Library path, set it to various differenet values - no success (Library path because of -L at the start).
- Found out that swiftCore is somehow missing in path:

> Unable to find swiftCore; please set SWIFT_LIBRARY_PATH (currently '')
>   to the folder containing swiftCore.

- Building from terminal to get more info about the error.
- Tried to restart computer, reinstall XCode and other most common things
- Tried other project - working without problem(project without pods)

Seems like this will be a diary till I commit suicide...

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a real device or in the simulator?

Comment: Same problem, when building for iOS device(iPhone6, none connected) i get same error but instead of iphonesimulator i got iphoneos - 6th bullet I think :)

Comment: But for all apps or only for a specific app you see this error?

Comment: For this specific app, had few more in Objective-C and they are working... Haven't tried some other swift2 project, but will do in 5-10 mins.

Comment: Yup, just this project.

Comment: Ok ... so this means the problem is in your App and not in the compiler/linker.. :-(

Comment: It is possible, but it report error for XCode, not the project itself... confused, I must be missing something... It could be because of the Pods/frameworks/libraries/whatever as well...

Comment: try to recreate the scheme of your App: delete the current scheme and make a new one

Comment: did you recently changed the name of the App?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91742/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-nickcatib).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 2 days of losing my mind, finally got to the solution. Hope it will save someones day :)

First, I decided to recreate the project file and pods to see if there is something wrong with them. It turned out they are fine. Project build without any issue.

So, clearly, problem was in the project/workspace file. I started comparing flag by flag, and ended up in changing the following:

- Duplicate Pods_X.framework - removed one
- `CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = NO` - was YES before
- `GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES;` - was no for debug
- `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";` - was something long before

If someone knows why this flags could produce something that painfull I will be happy to find out...